# Rearrange array so that no adjacent values are the same in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am in need to shuffle an array in a random order without two concurrent values being the same.

```
$array("red", "green", "blue", "red", "green", "blue", "red", "green", "blue", etc);
```

The output should be any valid array containing all the values in a random order without two values being adjacent with each other.

valid options are thus:

```
$array("blue", "red", "blue", "green", "red", "blue", "green");
```

I was thinking about counting the amount of "red", "blue" and "green"

```
array_count_values($array);
array_count_values($array)["red"];
array_count_values($array)["green"];
array_count_values($array)["blue"];
```

And then perhaps create an array using the available amount of each string.

Comment: Well for the counting of data in an array [look at the manual for `array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Comment: Do you know if it is always going to be solve-able, eg like the starting point would never be (red, red, red, blue)?

Comment: The array will always be a list of red,green,blue in that order, ending on any of which. @mickmackusa I need it for php, so I asked it here.

Comment: @HugoCox sorry, I didn't notice the linked question's tags. Deleted flag.

Comment: @HugoCox Wait, so they are already in an order that satisfies your condition?  You just want to randomize it while maintaining the no-side-by-side condition?

Comment: @MrZander Correct.

Comment: Did you try to self-solve after reading the linked java solution?  Manually iterating/adjusting the elements is going to be more efficient that re-shuffling and checking the batch.

Comment: @mickmackusa the array will always be "red","green","blue,"red","green","blue",...,"green". (Ending on any of the three). Afaik it is thus always solvable to rearrange them in a random order and keep the no-side-by-side condition.

Comment: It's 02:30 here I go sleep, but the answer by Bill K on the linked answer seems to make sense to me. Thank you for your help and interest already. Have a good trip ;)

Comment: Basically, I need to fill an array of n keys with an equal amount of "red", "green" and "blue" values, where 1 or 2 of the strings can have an additional occurence depending on n. But keep the no-side-by-side condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my first method that aims to minimize looping to achieve the required outcome.

Code: ([Demo with 3 different arrays and echo & var_export throughout the process](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c0021f5e958af27be28ce9ea2182fcbf1f7caab1))

```
// add $array here
$length=sizeof($array);
shuffle($array);
$valcounts=array_count_values($array);

function consec_check($array){
    $loops=sizeof($array)-1; // last element will not have right side element for comparison
    for($i=0; $i<$loops; ++$i){
        if($array[$i]==$array[$i+1]){
            return false;  // consecutive equal values = invalid
        }
    }
    return true;
}

if(max($valcounts)<=ceil($length/2)){  // if logically possible to fix
    while(!consec_check($array)){  // while any two equal elements are consecutive          
        foreach(array_diff($valcounts,[1]) as $color=>$count){  // only bother with elements that occur more than once
            $colorkeys=array_keys($array,$color);  // color group keys
            for($i=0; $i<$count; ++$i){
                if($i>0 && $prevk+1==$colorkeys[$i]){  // identify consecutives elements with same color
                    if($colorkeys[0]!=0){  // safe to shift {$colorkeys[$i]} to first position
                        array_unshift($array,array_splice($array,$colorkeys[$i],1)[0]);
                    }elseif(end($colorkeys)!=$length-1){  // safe to push {$colorkeys[$i]} to the last position
                        array_push($array,array_splice($array,$colorkeys[$i],1)[0]);
                    }else{  // no easy option, find a safe location inside array (more frequently used as array length increases)
                        for($j=0; $j<$count; ++$j){
                            if($j>0 && $colorkeys[$j]-$prevj>3){  // if 3 off-colors between two elements                                   array_splice($array,$prevj+2,0,array_splice($array,$colorkeys[$i],1));
                                break;                          
                            }
                            $prevj=$colorkeys[$j];
                        }
                    }
                    $colorkeys=array_keys($array,$color);  // update color keys array for continued processing
                }
                $prevk=$colorkeys[$i];
            }
        }
    }
    var_export($array);  // valid
}else{
    echo "\n\n<a href=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XAYhNHhxN0A\">Array cannot be made valid.</a>";
}
```

And here is my second method that uses regex patterns.

Code:  ([Demo with 3 different arrays and echo & var_export throughout the process](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a3ee98cf8cfd3c6a98d5c47186188c07f4d89c02))

```
shuffle($array);
$string=implode(' ',$array);
$start_length=strlen($string);

foreach(array_unique($array) as $v){
    $pullcount=$pushcount1=$pushcount2=0;
    $string=preg_replace("/$v (?=$v)/","",$string,-1,$pullcount);  // remove the first value of each conflicting pair
    $string=preg_replace("/ \K(?<!$v )(?!$v)|^(?!$v)/","$v ",$string,$pullcount,$pushcount1);  // foreach removal, re-insert value(s) where valid
    if($pullcount<=$pushcount1){
        $string=preg_replace("/$(?<!$v)/"," $v",$string,$pullcount-$pushcount1,$pushcount2);
    }
    if($pullcount!=$pushcount1+$pushcount2){
        echo "failure while replacing $v $pullcount & ",$pushcount1+$pushcount2,"\n";
        break;
    }else{
        echo "successfully replaced $pullcount conflicts for $v\n";
    }
}

if($start_length==strlen($string)){
    $array=explode(" ",$string);
    var_export($array);
}else{
    echo "\n<a href=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XAYhNHhxN0A\">Array cannot be made valid.</a>";
}
```

My second method wins on brevity, but it may not be trustworthy in other cases where values contain spaces or when a value is a substring of another value.

Both methods avoid the possibility of an infinite loop and will indicate if the array cannot be made valid.

Comment: Thank you very much, this will help me get a lot further :)